# symfony 'use' vs. include_once

Tags: php, symfony

I'm just getting started with symfony (2), and I'm trying to port over some code from an existing class - but I'm getting a bit stuck trying to use 'old' paradigms within symfony framework.  I have the following code:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;
use AppBundle\Components\model\Customer;

class MyController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @Route("/index.php", name="index")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{ 
    include_once( 'AppBundle\Components\model\Customer.php' );
    $entity = new Customer();
    $this->get('logger')->info('Instance == > ' . isset($entity) );
    $this->get('logger')->info('Class exists == > ' . ( class_exists('Customer')  ? 'YES' : 'NO') );
```

Where Customer.php just contains an empty class called Customer.

However, this code always logs:

```
[2016-06-24 17:44:42] app.INFO: Instance == > 1 [] []
[2016-06-24 17:44:42] app.INFO: Class exists == > NO [] []
```

As you can see, I am doing both `use` and `include_once`.
But it seems I can create an instance, but `class_exists` returns false.
To me this seems a contradiction.  Can someone tell me how to set this up so that `class_exists` returns true.

Comment: `class_exists` needs FQCN. Try checking `class_exists('AppBundle\Components\model\Customer');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`use` merely establishes an alias so you can refer to the class name using a shorter name. The fully qualified class name is `AppBundle\Components\model\Customer`; the `use` statement allows you to refer to it simply using `Customer`.

***However***, when referring to classes using a string, you always need to use the fully qualified class name. Aliases established with `use` do not apply to strings, since those aren't bound to the lexical scope of `use` statements and hence cannot be reliably resolved against them.

This works:

```
class_exists('AppBundle\Components\model\Customer')
```

Comment: shoudnt this work too? `class_exists(Customer::class)` - at least in php >=5.5.
see http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class

Comment: Sure, because that gives you the fully qualified class name as a string.